# return parent observable within child subscription

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I'm trying to `return` a boolean from within an another observable's subscription. However, I can't get the `return` to bubble-up to the parent method.

I realize that I'm `return`ing in the context of the subscription, but how do I tell `canDeactive` that the `dialog.result.subscibe` subscription is done and able to return a boolean?

```
  canDeactivate(): Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean {
    const settings: DialogSettings = {
      title: 'Please confirm',
      content: 'Are you sure want to leave without saving your changes?',
      actions: [
        { text: 'No'},
        { text: 'Yes', primary: true }
      ]
    };

    if (!this.isSaved && this.updatedPositions.length) {
      // return confirm('Do you want to discard the changes?');



      const dialog: DialogRef = this.dialogService.open(settings);

      dialog.result.subscribe((result: DialogResult) => {

        if (!(result instanceof DialogCloseResult) && result['text'] === 'Yes') {
          console.log('action', result);
          console.log('returning false');
          return false;

        } else {
          console.log('dialog.close()');
          dialog.close();
          return true;
        }

      })

    } else {
      console.log('else');
      return true;
    }

  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dialog.result` is an asynchronous call.Its similar to returning from a callback which obviously cant reflect to main method. Effectively you are  returning nothing in `true` part of your call.

Don't subscribe the changes , return observable as it is. Use map to convert the data.

```
return dialog.result.map((result: DialogResult) => {

    if (!(result instanceof DialogCloseResult) && result['text'] === 'Yes') {
      console.log('action', result);
      console.log('returning false');
      return false;

    } else {
      console.log('dialog.close()');
      dialog.close();
      return true;
    }

  })
```

And to keep it consistent , in the main else , at the bottom most.  Return an Observable .

```
} else {
  console.log('else');
  return Observable.of(true);
}
```